# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to implement logout funcationality in the Desktop Browser webpage environment

Tags: security, browser, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to implement a logout functionality for my Worklight app. Specifically, the Desktop Browser webpage environment.

My authenticationConfig.xml is as follows:

```
<resource id="MyApp" securityTest="MyAppTest">
            <urlPatterns>/apps/services/www/MyApp/*</urlPatterns>
         </resource> 

<customSecurityTest name="MyAppTest">
            <test realm="MyAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

<realm name="MyAppRealm" loginModule="MyAppLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="login.html" />
            <onLoginUrl>/apps/services/www/MyApp/desktopbrowser/default/index.html</onLoginUrl>
</realm>

<loginModule name="MyAppLogin">
            <className> com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RDBMSLoginModule </className>
            <parameter name="dsJndiName" value="jdbc/myapp"/>
            <parameter name="principalsQuery">
            SELECT user_id, password, display_name FROM users WHERE user_id=?
            </parameter>
</loginModule>
```

So far I have tried using Worklight client APIs

```
WL.Client.logout("MyAppRealm", {onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp}); 
WL.Client.logout(null, {onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp});
```

but that didn't work with errors around "realm is not defined". Could anyone please suggest why I might be seeing "realm is not defined" error?

Alternatively is there a different way to logout the user from my app (accessing the session directly?).

Comment: You say "desktop app". Which environment are you actually working on? The only Desktop environment in Worklight is Adobe AIR. Is this your environment? Perhaps you mean Windows Store app?

Comment: Also, adding just your authenticationConfig.xml is not enough; Add your actual JS code where you try to login and logout.

Comment: I am using desktopbrowser environment, that's why I called it a desktop app.

Comment: So that's basically HTML/JS that lives on your server and is fetched and run on your browser. Thanks. Please refer to my second question.

Comment: Also please inform what version of Worklight you are currently using.

Comment: there is no other code to be fair. I've tried using WL.Client.logout("MyAppRealm", {onSuccess:  WL.Client.reloadApp}); as well as WL.Client.logout(null, {onSuccess:  WL.Client.reloadApp}); - both of those didn't work..

I think the way I implemented the login I don't have a challenge handler etc in my app and I do all the login related work before loading the application. To do so I rely fully on RDBMSLoginModule. However I am not sure how to logout with such an approach. Possibly that is why my realm is accessible from the WL client API.

Comment: I am using Worklight 6.1

Comment: I've also played with cookies for a bit trying to set the session cookie to expire but after reading up on this it seems to be the wrong way to do it.. Also I can't get hold of the session cookie from my document - I think it's protected or something..

Comment: In terms of Login, I am using the default login.html provided with Worklight

Comment: I am not sure why you say there is no other code... you've only defined realms, not functionality.

Comment: Isn't the functionality implemented inside RDBMSLoginModule? Please explain what exactly do you mean. All I have is the login.html (default Worklight one) and the xml config (above), which allows me to login to the application. Entering the wrong credentials will fail the login, clearing browser history will log the user out, entering the right credentials will redirect to the app - therefore I thought I had the functionality supplied by Worklight classes.

Comment: You say you've used "Worklight client APIs but that didn't work", so what did you try? Add those code snippets.

Comment: I've added them above. Here they are again:
WL.Client.logout("MyAppRealm", {onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp});
WL.Client.logout(null, {onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp});

Answer (score 0):

The Login Module that you are using is no longer exist in Worklight framework (com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RDBMSLoginModule).

More information about how to use login modules can be found here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security
(Look for Form-Based authentication, Adapter-Based authentication and Custom Authenticator and Login Module).

You can also look here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_security_framework.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What exactly do you mean the RDBMSLoginModule no longer exists? According to the Infocenter it exists. Here it is in the Worklight 6.1 documentation following the link you've provided:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_database_login_module.html